# Saving data-URI to media library

Tags: plugin-development, ajax, uploads, media

I have a [TinyMCE plugin](http://www.wordpress.org/plugins/axis) that generates PNG images using `HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL()` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL)). Currently, I'm just displaying them on the backend by putting the data-URI in an image tag, but I'd really like to add these to the WordPress Media Library.

**What's the best (i.e., VIP-compliant) way of uploading images currently serialised as a base64-encoded data-URI?**

Here's my upload function so far:

```
<?php

/**
 * AJAX callback that inserts chart as attachment into the WP database
 */
public static function insert_axis_attachment() {
    // Get config
    $axis_config = json_decode( $_POST['axisConfig'] );

    if ( ! isset( $_POST['axisJS_nonce'] )
        || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['axisJS_nonce'] )
        || ! current_user_can( 'upload_files' )
        || ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $_POST['post_id'] )
        || ( isset( $axis_config->ID ) && ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $axis_config->ID ) )
    ) {
        return false;
    }

    // Begin saving PNG to filesystem
    if ( false === ( $creds = request_filesystem_credentials( 'admin-ajax.php', '', false, false, null ) ) ) {
        return false; // stop processing here
    }
    if ( ! WP_Filesystem( $creds ) ) {
        request_filesystem_credentials( 'admin-ajax.php', '', true, false, null );
        return false;
    }
    global $wp_filesystem;
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $chart_filename = sanitize_title_with_dashes( $axis_config->chartTitle ) . '_' . time() . '.png';
    $filename = trailingslashit( $upload_dir['path'] ) . $chart_filename;
    $uriPhp = 'data://' . substr( $_POST['axisChart'], 5 ); // Via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735414/php-data-uri-to-file/6735458#6735458
    $binary = wpcom_vip_file_get_contents( $uriPhp );
    $wp_filesystem->put_contents(
        $filename,
        $binary,
        FS_CHMOD_FILE // predefined mode settings for WP files
    );

    // Insert or update attachment.
    if ( ! $axis_config->ID ) {
        $attachment = array(
            'guid' => $upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $filename ),
            'post_title' => $axis_config->chartTitle,
            'post_content' => '', // Must be empty string
            'post_status' => 'published',
            'post_mime_type' => 'image/png',
            'post_status' => 'inherit',
        );

        $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $_POST['post_id'] );

        // Make sure that this file is included, as wp_generate_attachment_metadata() depends on it.
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

        // Generate the metadata for the attachment, and update the database record.
        $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );
        wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
        update_post_meta( $attach_id, '_axisWP', $axis_config );
        echo esc_attr( $attach_id );
        die();
    } else {
        update_attached_file( $axis_config->ID, $filename );
        update_post_meta( $axis_config->ID, '_axisWP', $axis_config );
        echo esc_attr( $axis_config->ID );
        die();
    }
}
```

Is how I'm using `WP_Filesystem` and `wp_insert_attachment()` correct? Or should I find some way to use `media_handle_upload()` instead?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure this is good place to ask in context of VIP compliance. There are _very_ few questions on it here and I am not confident we have people with such specific expertise hanging around. :\

Comment: @rarst I'm not even looking for VIP compliance so much as "I'm using WordPress's file handling classes properly", in the 12-factor-y manner VIP does it (i.e., if somebody has a "auto-upload all media library images to Amazon S3" plugin, it will work with that too. The above seems to work (updating with changes now), I'm just not sure it's hooking into the Media Library in a conventional fashion.

Comment: `media_handle_upload()` require a post id, and its "friend" `wp_handle_upload()` require a file exists in the `$_FILES` array, so I really think they don't fit your needs. IMHO you can use your current approach, probably I'd used [`wp_upload_bits`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_bits) instead of dealing with WP filesystem. Moreover, `wpcom_vip_file_get_contents` make your code **only** available in VIP contest, if you need for more *general* appoach a standard `file_get_contents` should be fine, and if you need to cache, then a transient should do the trick.

Comment: @G.M.I hadn't known about `wp_upload_bits` — that's super helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In a previous tinymce plugin I made - I set up a custom ajax transport so I could just use the blob right from the image src of a remote img instead of base64 on a data attribute, and then used the REST API to upload the image to the media library in js.

Base64 will be about 35% larger than a blob, so if there's a lot of charts or uploads, this will help reduce upload bandwidth quite a bit, even with just a single img,  performance should be considered since a lot of users tend to have a ton of plugins installed.  You probably already know how resource intensive just the editor and tinymce can be in the first place.

Plus, overall I hate breaking out of JS to PHP when it's not 100% necessary :P

Since you have the data set in base64 already - you could use a simple converter - there's plenty out there I just copied and pasted one I found for the example below. https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64toblob works fine if you wanted something quick to integrate into your build.

Here's a quick working example using a placeholder image base64 data, I just threw it in a theme for testing, but you can use it wherever you want:

theme/functions.php:

```
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'js_plugin_name_scripts' );

    function js_plugin_name_scripts() {
        wp_register_script( 'js-plugin-name', get_parent_theme_file_uri( 'js/js-plugin-name.js' ), array( 'wp-api' ) );
        wp_localize_script( 'wp-api', 'wpApiSettings', array(
            'root' => esc_url_raw( rest_url() ),
            'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' )
        ) );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'js-plugin-name' );
    }
```

theme/js/js-plugin-name.js:

```
    // Wait for API load.
    wp.api.loadPromise.done( function() {

        var base64, blob;

        /**
         * Convert base64 data to blob.
         * 
         * @param {string} base64
         * @param {string} mime 
         */
        function base64ToBlob( base64, mime ) {
            mime = mime || '';
            var sliceSize = 1024;
            var byteChars = window.atob( base64 );
            var byteArrays = [];

            for ( var offset = 0, len = byteChars.length; offset < len; offset += sliceSize ) {
                var slice = byteChars.slice( offset, offset + sliceSize );

                var byteNumbers = new Array( slice.length );
                for ( var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++ ) {
                    byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
                }

                var byteArray = new Uint8Array( byteNumbers );

                byteArrays.push( byteArray );
            }

            return new Blob(byteArrays, {type: mime});
        }

        base64 = "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";

        blob = base64ToBlob( base64, 'image/png' );

        // Upload to media library.
        jQuery.ajax( {
            url: wpApiSettings.root + 'wp/v2/media',
            method: 'POST',
            beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-WP-Nonce', wpApiSettings.nonce );
                xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename=' + 'placeholder.png' );
            },
            data: blob,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        } ).done( function ( response ) {

            // Response contains the media details.
            console.log( response );
        } );
    });
```

The file will be incremented -1, -2 automatically like normal so you don't overwrite stuff yadda yadda, and response will contain the media object to with whatever you need.

some of the useful params in response:

```
    response.id = post id
    response.source_url = url to file ie http://local.wordpress.dev/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/placeholder.png
    response.title.rendered(or .raw) = media title if needed
    response.slug = media slug
    response.media_details.height = contains the original uploaded img height
    response.media_details.width = contains the original uploaded img width
    response.media_details.sizes = contains the various img sizes generated - ie full/thumb/sm/med/lrg etc --- don't always rely on naming conventions ;)!
```

If you converted to base64 then you could also just write a custom jquery ajax transport and grab the img src and skip doing all the base64 decode to blob stuff too, and it should help performance hits from encoding just to decode etc.

EDIT:

I forgot to mention: the REST API is available for any vip site, so this should be fine.  I'm assuming you're generating the charts in tinymce editor on the back end - so the user is already authenticated.  The above example is just passing the nonce in through the headers in an ajax request, which is a requirement for security on vip.

You can refer to documentation for compliance here: https://vip.wordpress.com/documentation/api/

Also I didn't notice you were using HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL() ! - You could just skip the decoding of b64 and get the blob directly since you're not fetching the image from a remote and trying to add it and use HTMLCanvasElement.toBlob() ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob))

Comment: congrats, first useful use of the rest api which is probably not trivial to replicate that I see